# R CMD SHLIB and oneMKL

Tags: r, compiler-errors, intel-mkl

I recently posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177870/integrating-a-c-subfunction-for-optimizing-r-code)  regarding the compilation of a .c code within the R desktop environment, and I want to express my gratitude for the assistance provided. Continuing my question I haven't been able to find out to compile and link oneMKL in R dekstop.

Intel has published [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/using-onemkl-with-r.html) instructions for using oneMKL with R, but it appears that the provided instructions are tailored for Linux.

Initially, I had the impression that since the following command works in the Command Prompt:

```
icx hello_ddot.c -o hello_ddot  /DMKL_ILP64  -I"%MKLROOT%\include"  mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib mkl_sequential_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib
```

It might be possible to achieve the same results in the R desktop environment by simply adding the paths for the library elements mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib, mkl_sequential_dll.lib, and mkl_core_dll.lib. However, it appears that this approach doesn't work as expected in R, and I encountered issues such as error messages.

```
> command <- 'R CMD SHLIB so_77177870.c -o outputname -Lc:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mkl/2023.1.0/lib/intel64'
> system(command)
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.2.0'
/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 3: `    echo gcc  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o fio fio-win.def so_77177870.o -Lc:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mkl/2023.1.0/lib/intel64 -L"c:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"c:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64" -lR ; \'
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk:16: outputname ] Error 2
[1] 1
```

Could you please assist me?
Best regards,
Anastasia